# How to split one column to two columns in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me :

```
First_name | first_name | middle_name
           |            |
rrrr eeee  |   rrrr     | eeee
           |            |    
rrr eeeeeee|   rrr      | eeeeeee  
           |            |       
rr eeeee   |   rr       | eeeee
```

I want to split the `first_name` to `first_name` and `middle_name`.

Thanks

Comment: please spend some time to write your question in a clear and proper manner so that others can help you.. also it would be great if you share with us what you had already tried.. we are here to help you not to do things for you :)

Comment: How are the fields separated? By space? Do you want to do the split in a query output or in the table itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just have to find a space character you can speed things up by removing regular expression

```
SELECT 
    substr(name, 1, instr(name, ' ')-1) first_name,
    substr(name, instr(name, ' ')+1) middle_name
FROM  TEST
```

or even

```
SELECT
  substr(name, 1, space_pos-1) first_name,
  substr(name, space_pos+1) middle_name
FROM (SELECT name,
             instr(name, ' ') space_pos
      FROM TEST)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this sql code will be useful:

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(name,'^[^ ]*')  first_name,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(name, '([[:alpha:]]+)$')   middle_name
FROM TEST
```

**Note:** this works if the name always will be **FIRSTNAME "SPACE" MIDDLENAME**.

You can run this here **[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fdea78/1)**.